# How to access an action or make a dispatch from inside the store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

This is a notification module in the store, I want to trigger the clear method from within the store itself to close each notification when they get triggered automatically after a couple of seconds. How can I achieve that?

```
export const mutations = {
    success(state, message, isModal) {
        state.type = 'success';
        state.message = message;
        state.show = true;
        state.isModalMsg = isModal;
        setTimeout(()=>{
            actions.clear(state);
        },3000);
    },
    error(state, message, isModal) {
        state.type = 'danger';
        state.message = message;
        state.show = true;
        state.isModalMsg = isModal;
    },
    clear(state) {
        state.type = null;
        state.message = null;
        state.show = false;
        state.isModalMsg = false;
    }
};

export const actions = {
    success({ commit }, message) {
        commit('success', message);
    },
    error({ commit }, message) {
        commit('error', message);
    },
    clear({ commit }) {
        commit('clear');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dispatch` from within the `success` action:

```js
success({ commit, dispatch }, message) {
    commit('success', message);
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch('clear');
    }, 2000)
},
```

Comment: I tried that but it throws an error saying 'dispatch is not defined'

Comment: Did you copy/paste the answer exactly?  Your code doesn't show `dispatch` in the destructure assignment